# ftp connection issue 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive'

Tags: c#, ftp

I am facing an ftp connection issue:

> 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive'

when downloading files by FTP Client in India.

I tried to change active / passive modes. In India we set `ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;` and `ftpRequest.Proxy = null;` and it worked.  But when I checked in the US Office it was giving error.

If I revert it, it works in US but fails in India. I have checked various posts, but am not getting a solution which will work in all conditions.

Comment: The is at client side. Server Is located at US

Comment: a bit of code might help understand the question better..